# What's the pythonic way of fetching a single value from a single row in cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

The query can either return 0 or 1 rows. I'm trying to fetch the id if there is one.

This works but I'm hoping I can end up with something simpler:

```
result = session.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email = %s", (email,))
if len(result.current_rows) is not 1:
    raise SystemExit("Account not found for {}".format(email))

id = result[0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like what's outlined in the [api docs here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html?highlight=resultset#cassandra.cluster.ResultSet)

Probably also worth checking that

1. No empty results are returned (as you do above)
2. Not more than one result is returned

So in your code:

```
if (len(result.current_rows) > 1:
   raise SystemExit("More than one result found for {}".format(email))
elif (len(result.current_rows) < 1:
   raise SystemExit("No results found for {}".format(email))
for result in results:
    # code to do things here with the end result
```

Its probably not a good idea to assume that element `[0]` will always contain the right result. Maybe have a boolean field value to check which user id is the current one and then iterate through the results until you hit that flag. Thats if you want to check over more than one result, in which case the `>1` check above is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Specify column name and access by column name:

```
result = session.execute("SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE email = %s", (email,))

result.id
```

Comment: That won't work because the resultset can have multiple rows. 
You need to do result[0].id but it's also possible that no rows are returned and then it errors.

Comment: You are right I forgot about it so maybe you can add limit?